# Python - Write For Loop items into CSV as new rows

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

Hi Ive been working a python script to collect a list of results and write those results into a csv file.

My code works, but it writes the results into one cell (joined by "~"). I would like to write each result into a new line.

I don't have a lot of experience, and I did search to the extent of my capabilities to do so. If you feel as if something eluded me, could you please let me know what I should have been searching for?

Here is my current code:

```
person_result_names = WebDriverWait(browser, 60, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'person_results'))).find_elements_by_css_selector("#person_info > div > div > div.name.variation")

wait_time(1)
all_persons = [ person.text.replace(',', '').replace('\n', ' ') for person in person_result_names ]
print(f"[**] Found {len(all_persons)} people")
person = '~'.join(all_persons)
print(person)


report_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#person_results > div > a')
            
all_urls = [ url.get_attribute('href') for url in report_links ]
print(f"[**] Found {len(all_urls)} report urls")
url = '~'.join(all_urls)
print(url)
            
time.sleep(5)

with open('3_results-output.csv', 'a') as fp:
    print(f"{row_id},{person},{url}", file=fp)
```

Don't worry about `row_id` variable in the last line. It's being pulled from another source. Thanks in advance to all of the helpful solutions.

**This is my current output:**

`ID` signifies each search query, so `ID 0` has 3 results for both Names and Urls. `ID 1` has 4 results each

```
ID | Names                                 | Urls
0  | John Doe~Joe Doe~Jay Doe              | http://www.link.com/1~http://www.link.com/2~http://www.link.com/3
1  | Jane Doe~Janet Doe~Jill Doe~Julia Doe | http://www.link.com/4~http://www.link.com/5~http://www.link.com/6~http://www.link.com/7
```

**This what Id like the output to look like:**

```
ID | Names     | Urls
0  | John Doe  | http://www.link.com/1
0  | Joe Doe   | http://www.link.com/2
0  | Jay Doe   | http://www.link.com/3
1  | Jane Doe  | http://www.link.com/4
1  | Janet Doe | http://www.link.com/5
1  | Jill Doe  | http://www.link.com/6
1  | Julia Doe | http://www.link.com/7
```

**Update**

Here is the code that ended up working for me. Thanks to @Tim Post for pointing me in the right direction. I just need the writing method to include all results. The code below worked for me:

```
person_result_names = WebDriverWait(browser, 60, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'person_results'))).find_elements_by_css_selector("#person_info > div > div > div.name.variation")

wait_time(1)
print("\tScraping People\n")
all_persons = [ person.text.replace(',', '').replace('\n', ' ') for person in person_result_names ]
print(f"[**] Found {len(all_persons)} people")

wait_time(1)

report_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#person_results > div > a')

all_urls = [ url.get_attribute('href') for url in report_links ]
print(f"[**] Found {len(all_urls)} report urls")

with open('3_results-output.csv', 'a') as fp:
    for person, url in zip(all_persons, all_urls):
        print(f"{row_id},{person},{url}", file=fp)
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to the site. I've modified the wording in your answer related to your experience level so it points at something helpful folks can do if they want. Also, I removed quite a few condescending comments from others - I'm sorry you experienced that, it's not who we are.

Comment: @TimPost thank you. I'll use this approach moving forward. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following kind of approach. It makes use of Python's CSV library to help with writing the rows to the file:

```
import csv

person_result_names = WebDriverWait(browser, 60, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'person_results'))).find_elements_by_css_selector("#person_info > div > div > div.name.variation")

wait_time(1)
all_persons = [person.text.replace(',', '').replace('\n', ' ') for person in person_result_names]
print(f"[**] Found {len(all_persons)} people")

report_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#person_results > div > a')
all_urls = [ url.get_attribute('href') for url in report_links ]

print(f"[**] Found {len(all_urls)} report urls")

with open('3_results-output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["ID", "Names", "Urls"])    # Write the header
    
    row_id = 0
    
    for person, url in zip(all_persons, all_urls):
        csv_output.writerow([row_id, person, url])
```

Obviously you will need to add another loop somewhere to deal with multiple `row_id`, but this at least shows how you can write to a file correctly. It assumes `all_persons` and `all_urls` are of equal length.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks a lot for you input on this issue that Im having. Your solution records partial results. For testing purposes I gave my script an input of 3 results pages, which I want to collect the data from. The code you provided only records results from the last input page (#3) and it doesn't record any results from pages that comes before the last row (#1 and #2). Do you have any idea how to include all of the rows not just the last row? I hope Im explaining the results correctly. Please let me know if you need any more details from me. Thanks again!